# Storing dates in UTC after updating the user entered time zone to reflect proper UTC time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Event model which has start and end date/times and an associated time zone.

I need the date times submitted to be stored in the correct version of UTC based off of the time zone entered.

Example, if the user submits 2014-04-24 7PM EST

The database should be:

> 2014-04-24T23:00:00.000Z

Not this:

> 2014-04-24T19:00:00.000-07:00

Ok, I know rails stores everything in UTC, *but I need to store the UPDATED UTC time based off the time zone* - since my form is 3 fields, x2 date/time & x1 time zone

This is my model validation I thought would work properly:

```
  def calc_utc_based_off_timezone
    time_zone = self.time_zone

    puts "start date before assignment: "
    puts self.start_date

    self.start_date = self.start_date.in_time_zone(time_zone)
    self.end_date = self.end_date.in_time_zone(time_zone)

    puts "start date after assignment: "
    puts self.start_date
  end
```

**Entered in my form:**

> 2014-04-24 - 19:00
>
> 2014-04-26 - 19:00
>
> est

**Output:**

> start date before assignment:
>
> 2014-04-24 19:00:00 UTC
>
> start date after assignment:
>
> 2014-04-24 19:00:00 UTC

**What I'm expecting:**

> start date before assignment:
>
> 2014-04-24 19:00:00 UTC
>
> start date after assignment:
>
> 2014-04-24 23:00:00 UTC <-- updated UTC to reflect the time zone

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're trying to convert to a zone and back to UTC? You will never get a different value from a circular conversion. `in_time_zone` doesn't add hours or anything. It seems here you need to extract everything apart from the timezone from your time using a local timezone and then convert to UTC.

Comment: @aledalgrande Hrmmm, guess I'm thinking about it wrong.  It's hard to believe no ones ever done this / or that there aren't date functions to handle this.. If I do the extract you're referring too, you mean manually adding or subtracting times?

Comment: Either that or you'll have to generate the time in a way that it already has a timezone different from UTC. You are currently doing this: UTC -> something else -> UTC. That doesn't change the final time. You need to do: something else -> UTC.

Comment: @canigetabreak there is no need to manually calculate the timezone offset. Just set the Time.zone = "EST" or whatever and rails will interpret the input time as if its in that time zone. And what do you mean by 'Updated UTC'? Rails applies the offset and stores the time in utc, when retrieving any datetime object rails grabs the Time.zone and then applies it showing you the time in your timezone, while the utc time in the DB hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is support for Time objects with Time Zones in the [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-getutc) class.
As long as you set the Time zone before giving the params to the new object function `Event.new(params[:event])` rails will apply the offset that is set, and interpret as if its in that time zone.

```
# example params like the request
params = {
          time_zone:"EST",
          event:{
            start_date:"2014-04-24 - 19:00",
            end_date:"2014-04-26 - 19:00"}
          }   

Time.zone = params[:time_zone] # pulled from a time_zone_select field
@event = Event.new(params[:event])
```

if you have separate time and date fields, just combine them into whichever field holds the datetime in the database.

```
params[:event][:start_date] = "#{params[:event][:start_date]} #{params[:event][:start_time]}"
params[:event][:end_date] = "#{params[:event][:end_date]} #{params[:event][:end_time]}"

@event = Event.new(params[:event])
```

The timezones offset will be automatically applied and you should get the following if you inspect the object.

```
> puts @event.start_date
2014-04-25 00:00:00 UTC
> puts @event.end_date
2014-04-27 00:00:00 UTC
```

Here is a great guide that deals with Rails and Time Zones - [The Exhaustive Guide to Rails Time Zones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

Comment: So moral of the story is to do that on the controller side validations as opposed to the model side??  Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Not necessarily a 'validation' but all you need to do is make sure that the Time.zone is set somewhere before you create the new object.You could do that in the application controller in a before_filter or right here before the actual code.

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I had such a hard time with that, but your explanation helped.

Comment: I spent weeks on this when I was learning it, here is an excellent guide that makes it more clear.    [The Exhaustive Guide to Rails Time Zones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is something in Rails ActiveSupport for this,

```
Time.parse("2014-04-24 - 19:00").in_time_zone

Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:00:00 UTC +00:00

Time.parse("2014-04-24 - 19:00").getutc

2014-04-24 23:00:00 UTC
```

You can also specify the detail and format (like iso8601) of your response by passing additional arguments like this:

```
> Time.parse("2014-04-24 - 19:00").getutc.iso8601(2)
"2014-04-24T23:00:00.00Z"
> Time.parse("2014-04-24 - 19:00").getutc.iso8601(3)
"2014-04-24T23:00:00.000Z"
```

Documentation for ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-getutc